# ArcGIS Server 10.2: Could not connect to the Map Server

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, map-service, basic-license-level

I've installed an ArcGIS for Server 10.2 Enterprise Basic on my Windows server(Windows Server 2008 R2(x64), SQL Server 2008).

I can publish service by ArcGIS Desktop 10.2 on my server, but when I connect to the server as a user. I could only use the Feature service.

If I try to connect to the map service, ArcGIS Desktop will show the ERROR: Could not connect to the Map Server.

I checked ArcGIS Server logs, it shows: HRESULT: 0x80004005.

Can the Enterprise Basic Edition only publish the feature service without the map service?

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1):

At this point, it's helpful to review the ArcGIS Server [functionality matrix](http://www.esri.com/library/brochures/pdfs/arcgis-server-functionality-matrix.pdf). With Basic license, you can only publish feature services (technically, they are map services with Feature Access capability enabled).

In order to serve dynamic or cached map services, you need to have at least Standard license. Here is the screenshot of the page 14.

[image]